# Is the notion of an angle between vectors defined only in 2D and 3D?

Tags: linear-algebra

In linear algebra there is the notion of an angle between vectors. For example in the following well known equation:

$x.y = |x||y|cos(\theta$)

$\theta$ is the angle between vectors $x$ and $y$.

Is this notion of angle defined only in $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $\mathbb{R}^3$ or it is also defined in $\mathbb{R}^d$ where $d>3$

Thanks

Comment: This https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inner_product_space#Definition may help.

Comment: Note that even in $\mathbb R^d$ two vectors are still defining a dimension $2$ plane, (i.e. $\operatorname{Span}(u,v)$) where the notion of angle is well defined.

Answer (score 1):

The angle between tow vectors is well defined in any vector space in which an inner product is defined. The formula  $$ \cos (\theta ) = \frac {u.v}{|u||v|}$$ gives you the cosine of the angle between the vectors $u$ and $v$

Comment: so then we can define $\theta = cos^{-1} \frac{u.v}{|u||v|}$. But this time in dimensions > 3, it does not make sense to me why the cosine function is used to define the angle between vectors?

Comment: @Sanyo  Mn  You may want to study Orthogonal Polynomials to see the applications  of  angles in inner product spaces in general.